# Confusion around Bash command --- find -name '*s'

Tags: bash, find, glob

I'm currently learning Bash and have encountered the following problem.

With command `find -name '*s'`, I was expecting that the command will find every file with name `*s`, like literally `*s`, but instead, bash found every file that ended with `s`.

I thought everything inside a single quote will be treated like a normal string. What is missing from my understanding?

I guess a natural follow on question would be:

I expect `find -name *s` to be expanded, but instead bash gives me the following message

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `-name` option of `find` expects a string input and hence you need to pass it within single quotes. For escaping the special characters use `\`

In this case `find . -name '\*s'` will produce the desired result